# windowsxp sp3 disable interface from command line

Tags: windows-xp, command-line-interface

I need to mass disable interfaces on windows machines (more than 100 machines).
I tried using:

```
netsh interface set "VirtualBox Host-Only Network" disable
```

But it does not work. (I found an article describing that it works on win 2003 server).
I can run commands remotely with psexec.

Do you have any hints?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be helpful if you were more specific than "does not work" by including an error message. You could also include a link to the article you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that you need another "interface" keyword and "disabled" instead of "disable":

```
netsh interface set interface "VirtualBox Host-Only Network" disabled
```

Answer (score 1):

Disabling LAN interfaces with netsh doeas not work on Windows XP. The help shows following:

```
admin   - whether the interface should be enabled (non-LAN only)
connect - whtether to connect the interface (non-LAN only)
newname - new name for the interface (LAN only)
```